# Does installing android studio on linux require installing java too?

Tags: java, android-studio, ubuntu

I want to install Android Studio in Linux Ubuntu 22.04. Then, how to install Android Studio properly, and do i have to install java first? If I have to install java, what version of java should me to install? Thank you

Comment: Yes it does require the JDK. Do you want to build your apps for any particular version of android? If you want your apps to run on slightly older phones then use Java 8, or you can use a newer one, but target the build to java 8. If you want to run on new phones only then you can check which version you can currently build to (Java 11 is the latest supported version last time I checked)

Comment: I think it is not required to install Java manually. Android Studio automatically installs java and other android libraries. Manual installation of Java is required when you install any IDE of jet brains like Intellij Idea.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely. Android apps are written in Java. You need to have a JDK installed to compile and run the application code which you have written.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

At least with the latest Android Studio Giraffe, I believe this is bundled with the IDE now as I did not need to install a JDK and I have no JDK package installed in my OS.

Comment: I just installed the same version but could not find Java as option. How did you do that?

Comment: What do you mean by Java as an option?